# Establishing a unit converter which can be called globally through terminal

Tags: bash, unix, command-line-arguments, global

I would like to have a function (or may be some kind of executable) that can be called via Terminal from wherever I am (from any directory) and this function does a simple job of converting between units, e.g. from meter to feet. Is such task realizable? I can code in Fortran90 and C, the former being more familiar with than the latter. I work on MacOS X platform.

For the sake of simplicity let's say that my function written in C takes a string and print it in standard output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[4];
    strcpy(str, argv[1]);
    printf("input = %s \n",str);       
}
```

Then compiling it to generate an executable named "example". I would like to be able to call this program globally, so that by executing `$example abc` it will print `input = abc` in the terminal window. I have tried placing this executable under the same directory as the gcc's (gfortran, gcc, g++, etc) since this path has been set to the environment variable but it didn't work. I can't call it from outside this directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call it from anywhere in your system,  your application must be in a directory that is part of the variable **PATH**.

On terminal issue:

```
echo "$PATH"
```

or

```
printf "%s\n" $PATH
```

and you will see something like this:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

That is the list of locations where the system will search for the application.

Move you compiled application to any of those directories: `usr/local/bin` for example, enable the executable bit (**chmod +x**) and that's all.

Comment: So I simply first run `$chmod +x example`, and then I can call it by e.g. `$example abc`?
I am sorry right now I can't directly test that because the Mac I am using is actually in my office.
Also, why do I need to use chmod first, is it because it will enable the global property of my application? As I recall I have actually tried placing my application "example" in `usr/local/bin` but it didn't work either. It couldn't be called globally.

Comment: @nougako In Unix-like operating systems, files have a set of permissions: read, write, and execute. Typically, by default, a file will *not* have the execute permission and cannot be run. `chmod` (think "change mode") is used to modify files' permissions. `chmod +x` specifically, will enable the execute permission on whichever files you specify, allowing you to run them. `chmod` has nothing to do with where you can run it from, only if you can run it at all.

Comment: In some shells (*csh at least), the builtin `rehash` command must be issued before a new executable will be found in your $PATH of the current shell process.  Starting a new shell will also rehash the $PATH tree.

Comment: Thank you very much it works. Sorry for the late reply I had been really occupied last week and just got the chance to try your suggestion.